# Reversing a Link List using Iterative Approach

Tags: c++, linked-list, reverse, singly-linked-list, function-definition

What is wrong with my code for reversing a linked list?

```
void rev(node* &head)
{
    int flag=0;
    node* head1=NULL;
    while(head->next!=NULL)
    {
        node* temp1=head;
        node* temp2=head;
        while(temp1->next!=NULL)
        {
            temp2=temp1;
            temp1=temp1->next;
        }
        if(flag==0)
        {
            head1=temp1;
            flag++;
        }
        temp1->next=temp2;
        temp2->next=NULL;
    }
    head=head1;
    delete head1;
}
```

I was trying to solve a standard problem of reversing a link list. So i tried implementing this approach, however it seems to be going into infite loop, I am unable to understad why.

Comment: it does not compile. It is incomplete https://godbolt.org/z/n8f1faoPj

Comment: Two things, have you drawn on a piece of paper what happens with all the pointers? And second have you tried running your code in a debugger and verified that each step (pointer re-assignment) happens as you've drawn on paper? (Also note that single linked lists are not really that nice for reversing, if you need that often then use a doubly linked list).

Comment: i dont understand the code, but the last two lines are especially surprising. `head=head1; delete head1;`  `head` is the thing you modify because that caller passed it to you. Why do you delete the node that it points to ?

Comment: the "standard" way to reverse a linked list in C++ is `std::list::reverse`.

Comment: Another isssue I see is that reverse isn't a member function of a list class. Then you don't have to pass in the head pointer seperately and you can check the list is empty or not.

Comment: As part of your goal of "reversing a link list", do you believe that it is necessary to `delete` some random existing node in the list? If yes, why? If no, then what exactly do you expect that `delete` statement, at the end of the function, to accomplish?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Well the standard way would indeed be NOT to write your own list. But I assume this is for a datastructures class (which is not the same as learning proper C++)

Comment: @PepijnKramer indeed. I always get a little confused when they assume the implementation of a linked list is obvious. I dont think it is. I think details matter. And as they also seem to assume that it is obvious that in C++ a linked list is selfwritten, why not point them to the proper one ;)

Comment: Drawing it out on paper would have revealed the solution quite quickly. All you need to do to reverse a (singly) linked list is make the arrows point the other way, and then move the head pointer. And I'm not being facetious, either. That's literally the algorithm.

Comment: FWIW, I disagree with the close votes' reasoning. If anything, this would be a "details or clarity" issue. But I believe there to be enough code/information to provide an answer to the question being asked, so I have voted to re-open.

Comment: The issue appears to be that you traverse the entire list at every (outer) iteration and seem to just swap the final two elements forever. You never update `head`, so the outermost loop is infinite. You need to be changing pointers as you traverse, and you'll naturally know where to re-assign `head` when you reach the end; no need for a special check. This is an O(n) operation, and you made it a non-functional O(n^2).

Comment: @Charlie I have prepared a demonstration program that shows how a singly-linked list can be reversed but unfortunately  your question was already closed.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is invalid.

For example the passed pointer `head` can be equal to `nullptr`. In this case this while loop

```
while(head->next!=NULL)
```

already can invoke undefined behavior.

Or there is nothing to delete in the list but the function has these statements

```
head=head1;
delete head1;
```

that do not make sense.

Even if to remove the statement with the call of delete nevertheless this does not make the function correct. For example if the list contains only one node then this while loop

```
while(head->next!=NULL)
```

will not be executed. As a result the pointer `head` will be set to `NULL` due to this statement after the loop

```
head=head1;
```

because before the loop the pointer `head1` is set to `NULL`

```
node* head1=NULL;
```

Also it seems in this nested while loop

```
while(temp1->next!=NULL)
{
    temp2=temp1;
    temp1=temp1->next;
}
```

you are trying to find the last node in the list that at least is inefficient.

And your function is unclear and too complicated.

To write the function it is enough to learn the standard C++ function `std::exchange` declared in header `<functional>` that will make the code of the function more simpler and clear.

Here is a demonstration program that shows how the function that reverses a singly-linked list can be implemented.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};

void clear( node * &head )
{
    while ( head ) delete std::exchange( head, head->next );
}

void assign( node * &head, const int a[], size_t n )
{
    clear( head );

    for (node **current = &head; n--; current = &( *current )->next)
    {
        *current = new node{ *a++, nullptr };
    }
}

std::ostream & display( const node *const &head, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for (const node *current = head; current != nullptr; current = current->next)
    {
        os << current->data << " -> ";
    }

    return os << "null";
}

void reverse( node * &head )
{
    for ( node *current = head, *previous = nullptr; current != nullptr; previous = head )
    {
        head = std::exchange( current, current->next );
        head->next = previous;
    }
}

int main()
{
    node *head = nullptr;
    const int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    assign( head, a, std::size( a ) );

    display( head ) << '\n';

    reverse( head );

    display( head ) << '\n';

    clear( head );
}
```

The program output is

```
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 -> null
```

As you can see the function has only one for loop the compound statement of which contains only two statements

```
void reverse( node * &head )
{
    for ( node *current = head, *previous = nullptr; current != nullptr; previous = head )
    {
        head = std::exchange( current, current->next );
        head->next = previous;
    }
}
```

Without using the standard function `std::exchange` the function that reverses a list will have one more statement as for example

```
void reverse( node * &head )
{
    for ( node *current = head, *previous = nullptr; current != nullptr; previous = head )
    {
        head = current;
        current = current->next; 
        head->next = previous;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Charlie Thanks. I already upvoted your question.:)

Answer (score 2):

First, a mini code review:

```cpp
//
// Bigger issues implied by this function are that it is not a very good
// linked list, likely an extremely basic C-style list. However, that is
// beyond the scope of this question.
//
void rev(node* &head)
{
    int flag=0;  // Unnecessary
    node* head1=NULL;  // Prefer nullptr
    while(head->next!=NULL)
    {
        node* temp1=head;
        node* temp2=head;  // Choose better names
        while(temp1->next!=NULL)  // Traverse the entire list at every iteration
        {
            temp2=temp1;
            temp1=temp1->next;
        }
        if(flag==0)
        {
            head1=temp1;
            flag++;
        }
        temp1->next=temp2;  // Always and only swaps the last two elements
        temp2->next=NULL;

        // Never updates head in the loop; loop is infinite
    }
    head=head1;
    delete head1;  // head1 was pointing to a valid node; you just nuked your
                   // entire list
}
```

The algorithm is quite simple, and one that reveals itself when the problem is drawn using paper and pencil. You just need to make the arrows point the other way, and reassign the head. You are attempting that, but you don't change any pointers except for the final two nodes. You need to be changing them as you move through the list.

The special `head` check and `flag` are unnecessary. You will naturally arrive at the tail and can reassign head when you do so.

Here's the reworked algorithm:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct node {
  int data;
  node* next;

  node(int d) : data(d), next(nullptr) {}
};

//
// Bigger issues implied by this function is that it is not a very good
// linked list, likely an extremely basic C-style list. However, that is
// beyond the scope of this question.
//
void rev(node*& head) {
  node* prev = nullptr;
  node* curr = head;
  node* next = nullptr;  // Not immediately assigned to account for
                         // empty list.

  while (curr) {
    next = curr->next;  //
    curr->next = prev;  // This order of operations is very important
    prev = curr;        //
    curr = next;        //
  }

  head = prev;
}

int main() {
  node* list = new node{1};
  list->next = new node{2};
  list->next->next = new node{3};
  list->next->next->next = new node{4};
  list->next->next->next->next = new node{5};

  node* walker = list;
  std::cout << "Original list: ";
  while (walker != nullptr) {
    std::cout << walker->data << ' ';
    walker = walker->next;
  }
  std::cout << '\n';

  rev(list);
  std::cout << "Reversed list: ";
  walker = list;
  while (walker != nullptr) {
    std::cout << walker->data << ' ';
    walker = walker->next;
  }
  std::cout << '\n';

  // On the one hand, I don't delete my nodes. On the other,
  // the program is ending and the OS will clean up my mess.
  // This is generally a bad practice.
}
```

Output:

```
❯ ./a.out
Original list: 1 2 3 4 5 
Reversed list: 5 4 3 2 1
```

While it would require more code, a proper C++ linked list class would be strongly preferred to avoid the downright silly initialization required in `main()`.

And I understand that this code is likely just to understand this particular algorithm, but the C++ standard library does provide both singly and doubly linked lists, both of which are trivial to reverse.